# Are answers whose sole purpose seems to be the propagation of a particular sect on topic here?

Tags: discussion, answers

I mean, in particular, this answer: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/59972/25763

My first instinct was to flag it, however, seeing that already 2 ppl have downvoted it before me w/o flaggint it I started wondering if flagging this answer was appropriate.

The answer consists almost solely of a link to a YT video whose purpose seems to be the propagation of a particular sect, as well as attacking Catholicism. I haven't watched the whole video (it's almost 20mins long); so I'm not sure if this video touches the subject of the question; but even if it does it is clear that the primary purpose of this answer is the propagation of the answerer's particular sect.

Is such an answer on-topic here? Is it appropriate for me to flag such answers?

Comment: FLAG FLAG FLAG. yes, flag it. Total spam. A waste of our time. If enough flags come in on a single post or comment, auto-scripts will remove it, rather than a moderator having to take the time to handle it. This would be "community action", a desired and even preferred thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, that answer is (well, *was*) definitely deserving of flags.  Such an "answer" doesn't work well for this site for a number of reasons, such as:

- It doesn't provide the Catholic view of the legality of non-Catholic religions, and thus is "not an answer"
- It basically consists of a link to an external site, which we strongly discourage – while references are encouraged, it's essential that answers here stand on their own
- It's quite "spammy" – given that it's just a link, and an irrelevant link at that

So yes, this should have been flagged as either Not An Answer, or Very Low Quality, or Spam.  And don't worry – it was indeed flagged almost immediately by one of our other users.  Those flags are only visible to moderators, not regular users, but they start the process of eliminating such content.

I hope in the future you'll feel free to flag things like this.  If you're not sure, it's fine to flag anyway; you might get a "declined" flag or two, but we appreciate your efforts in cleaning up the site.  Thanks!